# Outlook 2010 html footer font family not applying after being sent

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email, outlook-2010

I am trying to get Calibri sans-serif font to apply to outbound html emails from Outlook 2010, but I am failing to do so. I guess this is all I have to say about it.

The code I am using:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="FFFFFF" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif !important; font-size: 20px;">
      <td>
        <h1 style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif !important; font-size: 32px; font-weight: normal;">
          <span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif !important; font-size: 32px; font-weight: normal;">Test name 1</span>
        </h1>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have also tried a plethora of other stuff, including:

```
<!--[if gte mso 14]>
    <style>
    h1, p, a, div, span, tr {
        font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .outlook {
    font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

The code displays fine in outlook 2010, when I'm writing the email (image below).

[image]

But when it is sent and received on the other end, the sans-serif has been copmpletely stripped from the raw email, resulting in this:

[image]

Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: Does the other hand actually have Calibri installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calibri is only available on Windows as standard fonts, so all other recipients using MAC or Linux doesn't have Calibri installed and therefore shows your text in default font of that system.

Comment: Goddamnit, but you are completely right. I was so obsessed with finding the error in Outlook that I forgot to think of the bigger picture.